# Neorg crashes Neovim

Tags: neovim

## Solution

An update to `0.95` actually just solved this

## Original Post

I am trying to setup Neorg for notetaking and have several problems so far:

1. If I add `ft = "norg"` to my plugin spec, and load any `.norg` file, `nvim` crashes my session, it just becomes unresponsive and I have to kill my tmux session.
2. If I leave that out, it still occassionaly crashes, so far randomly, but also often when doing `:h neorg`.

There is also a general confusion about the documentation referring to a `init.lua`, I only created a plugin spec like this:

```
return {
    "nvim-neorg/neorg",
    build = ":Neorg sync-parsers",
    -- ft = "norg",
    -- tag = "*",
    dependencies = {
        "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
        "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
        "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects",
        "nvim-cmp"
    },
    config = function()
        require("neorg").setup {
            load = {
                ["core.defaults"] = {},  -- Loads default behaviour
                ["core.concealer"] = {}, -- Adds pretty icons to your documents
                ["core.dirman"] = {      -- Manages Neorg workspaces
                    config = {
                        workspaces = {
                            notes = "~/Notes/General",
                            kc = "~/Notes/kc",
                        },
                    },
                },
                ["core.integrations.nvim-cmp"] = {},
                ["core.integrations.treesitter"] = {},
                ["core.syntax"] = {},
                ["core.completion"] = { config = { engine = "nvim-cmp", name = "[Norg]" } },
            },
        }
    end,
}
```

Shouldn't this be enough?

I also ran `:TSUpdate norg` and did all that, I'm just wondering what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated!

### Edit

Further issues I am having:

- I can't fold headings with `zf`:

```
E350: Cannot create fold with current 'foldmethod'
```

Upon running `:set foldmethod?`:

```
foldmethod=expr
```

- Nothing happens inside math mode, I thought it would render somehow at least somethings, whether its inline or in `@math`.
- Is there a way to change the standard indent from 2 to 4? This just works against my standard indent of 4, and its a bit weird to fight it all the time
- `:h neorg` crashes very very consistently.
- Journal mode crashes instantly, which is the feature I want to get to work the most. It does create a file and everything but once it goes inside the file it just freezes.
- Link traversal mode etc. work, a lot of stuff works. But this is sadly far from a stable experience.

Comment: It looks like a nvim-neorg issue at first. Maybe should you  ask your question in the issue tracker. Which version of Neovim are you using?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Hi, thanks for your reply! It is 0.94. I wanted to upgrade to 0.95 but its not possible with homebrew, I can only get the nightly build with --HEAD. Is that something you'd recommend?

Comment: I suspect that your installation of [treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) is incomplete or wrong. Could you describe how you did install it? Could you give more information about the "crash"? What is the content of the stack trace if any?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt super sorry for the long reply. After your initial comment I found a way to update, and it was indeed that. Everything works perfectly fine now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am glad to hear that ypu have found a solution to your problem :-)